# getting id of a one module into another in sugarcrm

Tags: soap, logic, hook, sugarcrm

**What I want?**

I want Id of a  one module into another module.

**description**:-

I have created two module 1. Invoice  2. payment.  between this two module there is a one to many relationship.

Now I  am using a logic hook to calculate data in payment.
but my problem is that  my total amount field is present in In voice module.  if I use a hardcode id of invoice module it work properly.

but I am not getting the id of current record from $bean

**var_dump($bean) return Null**

the code is:

```
<?php

// prevents directly accessing this file from a web browser
if(! defined('sugarEntry') || ! sugarEntry)
  die('Not A Valid Entry Point');


class Process
{

  function process(&$bean, $event, $arguments)
  {

    $focus = new invoi_invoice();
    $id='d5112b7d-2e75-cba5-0e72-51e8ed34dcb7';


    $a=$focus->retrieve($id);
    $b=$a->totalamount;

    // calculate item profit
    $bean->t_remaing_amount_c = ($b - $bean->t_amount_paid_c);

    // calculate sale profit
    if(!empty($bean->t_no_of_rooms_c))
    {
      $bean->t_amount_per_room_c= ($bean->t_total_amount_c / $bean->t_no_of_rooms_c);
    }

  }

}

?>
```

this code working perfect because id is hardcoded. when I use $bean->id to fetch id of record it does not work actually  var_dump($bean);  retun null value.

**please help me  how to fetch id of current record.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all some words regarding your sentence:

> when I use $bean->id to fetch id of record it does not work actually var_dump($bean); return null value

As I understand you use logic hook in Payment module. Thus $bean parameter in your Process::process() references to record in Payment module. Can't imagine why you need to fetch an id of current record (i.e. an instance of Payment class) if it's already passed by reference as function parameter. In your example you hardcoded an id of Invoice module record. So which module record do you actually need to be retrieved? Hope you really need Invoice module one. So we have a case here to grab a parent record. A little later about that.

I think that the reason your var_dump() call returns null is that you use it in before_save logic hook. "before save" means that focused bean still have no 'id' property because... it  just have not been saved yet! If you have a look at SugarBean::save() method you'll find out that 'id' property (in form of UUID actually) is generated with create_guid() function being called in that method. Since you don't call $bean->save() you don't have an id property. Clear as that.

Back to grabbing parent record.

There are number of ways to do that.

- In one of my old projects I use SugarBean::get_linked_beans() method to get an array (consisting of 1 element in one-to-many relationship) of parent records.
- [Here](http://developers.sugarcrm.com/wordpress/2012/03/23/howto-using-the-bean-instead-of-sql-all-the-time/) you may find some ideas how to use other SugarBean class methods to get parent record.
- Try to explore $_REQUEST global to find a key keeping parent record id
- Have a look at cache/MODULE_NAME/BEAN_NAMEvardefs.php file and try to find field definition with 'type' => 'link' and 'relationship' key named after your one-to-many relationship. I mean something like this:

  ```
  'invoices_s892lyment_ida' =>

     array(

      'name' => 'invoices_s892lyment_ida',

      'type' => 'link',

      'relationship' => 'invoices_payments', 

      'source' => 'non-db',

      ...

      );
  ```

Then you may use something like:

```
$invoice = new Invoice();

$invoice->retrieve($bean->invoices_s892lyment_ida);
```

Comment: first of all thanks sir  for giving me a suggestion , and whatever you understand  all things is correct.

Comment: when i use $invoice = new invoi_invoice();
$id=$invoice->retrieve($bean->invoi_invoice_t_hotel_payment_1invoi_invoice_ida); it give me Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /drive2b/current/sugarhotel.devprolive.com/code/include/database/MysqliManager.php on line 254
 Catchable fatal error: Object of class Link2 could not be converted to string in /drive2b/current/sugarhotel.devprolive.com/code/data/SugarBean.php on line 2293